# PHP issue (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input)

Tags: php, syntax

It seems the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" usually has to do with JS, not PHP, which is my problem.

The issue lies somewhere in these few lines of code:

```
function sanitize_output($buffer){
  $search = array('/\>[^\S ]+/s', '/[^\S ]+\</s', '/(\s)+/s');
  $replace = array('>', '<', '\\1');
  $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
  return $buffer; 
}
```

Looks like Chinese to me but if someone sees what the syntax problem is let me know.

Comment: _“The issue lies somewhere in these few lines of code”_ – no, it doesn’t, these line by themself are parsed perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all your functions are closed. These errors usually appear when you have not enough or to many brackets. The posted lines of code are fine.

Comment: Not as far as I know. But a modern texteditor like notepad++ will highlight the end bracket if you select the startbracket. I will take some time but it is a way to find the problem...